# Error on SQL query right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

i'm trying to create a trigger on my database but i'm getting this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 " but i can't understand why. This is the query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cancella_associativa AFTER DELETE ON libro
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM annuncio_autore 
        WHERE libro.`idLibro` = annuncio_autore.`idAnnuncio`;
    END
```

Using phpMyAdmin, thanks in advance.

Comment: No need for a trigger. Just use InnoDB's CASCADE ON DELETE option

Comment: You probably just need a `delimiter` statement before and after the definition.  You also need to define `libro`.

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe it's a table engine that doesn't support foreign keys or delete cascades (like MyISAM).

Comment: @steffen Yes. The world is full of possibilities.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry i changed to InnoDB and used to ON DELETE and it's ok!

Answer (score 0):

The `;` after the line that contains `WHERE` ends your (incomplete) `CREATE TRIGGER` query. You need to change the delimiter:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER ... //
delimiter ;
```

For more information see [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).